# ThreadPool in Flask

Tags: python, flask, python-multithreading

This is a piece of my code. I am asking if I can serve many clients without reaching any errors (because I have limited the processes in `2`)?

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

pool = ThreadPool(processes=2)

@app.route("/query/<lng>/<lat>/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def query(lng,lat):
   t1 = pool.apply_async(queryA, (lng, lat ))
   t2 = pool.apply_async(queryB, (lng, lat ))

   results = {}
   results['a'] = t1.get()
   results['b'] = t2.get()

   return dumps(results)
```

I previously had the `pool = ThreadPool(processes=2)` inside the function but I got `error: can't start new thread`:

```
def query(lng,lat):
    pool = ThreadPool(processes=2)
    #rest
```

Therefore I would like to ask if I can serve more than 1 clients simultaneously without any errors? If no what is the correct code I should use?

Is `pool` now global and if I have 2 simultaneous request I will hit the limit (2x2=4 running requests)?

Comment: The flask developement server is *not* meant for production use. When you need to serve multiple clients you put your flask app behind a  web server. Apache, nginx, gunicorn.. plenty of choices.

Comment: @msvalkon I run it with gunicorn

Comment: Then what exactly is the problem your are trying to solve?

Comment: @msvalkon Am I going to hit a thread limit with the first snippet of code? Because I had the second snippet/version and the server was throwing the error mentioned above (`error: can't start new thread`).

Comment: to what problem is this threading snippet a solution to? Gunicorn solves the problem of serving stuff to many clients.

Comment: Why do you feel you need two extra threads to handle your request?

Comment: I use Flask as a layer to get data from the database. However I need two different queries to make to the database. In order to save time I create two async calls so I don't have to wait the first in order to start the second database call. For a reason that I cannot understand (because I just dont know :) ), if I had the `pool = ThreadPool(processes=2)` inside the route-funtion I was getting that error.

Answer (score 0):

As of your comments, you're using a Flask webapp as a layer on your database connection.

You can't do asynch database query easily with that setup but maybe you can move the problem to the client.
Is the client able to issue multiple http queries asynchronously? If yes you can simply split your query function in 2 distinct route function and aggregate data on the client.
This way you can scale both queries and let gunicorn manage concurrency.

Another approach is using an event-based asynch web framework such as Tornado instead of Flask (or only for some urls).